# Swift: Format a a start and end date into a single string

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I have these two dates in string format:

```
let startDate = "2018-06-14"
let endDate = "2018-06-17"
```

I would like to format them together as such:

> June 14-17, 2018

However, if the start and end date fall on different months it should be formatted like this:

> June 29 - July 1, 2018

And if the start and end date fall on different years it should be formatted like this:

> December 29, 2018 - January 1, 2019

Is there an easy way of doing this using Swift's native `DateFormatter`?

Is there a popular pod that can help with this?

What's the best practice to accomplish this formatting?

Comment: I would look into the `DateComponents`class for this, see [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponents).

Comment: Use `DateIntervalFormatter`. But first create two `Date` instances from your strings.

Comment: A `DateIntervalFormatter` with `dateStyle = .long` and `timeStyle = .none` should get you pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer:

```
   if let startDate = startDateString.toDate(withFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd"),
        let endDate = endDateString.toDate(withFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd") {
        let formatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        dateLabel.text = formatter.string(from: startDate, to: endDate)
    }
```

And this extension:

```
extension String {

    func toDate(withFormat format: String) -> Date? {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter.date(from: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't as useful as it could be because `toDate(withFormat:)` is not a standard method.

Comment: I've added the function toDate(withFormat format: String)